# Cells not showing for the UICollectionViewController inside a Container View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm encountering with the following problem:

In XCode using storyboard, I have `UIViewController` with a Container View.

By default, the Container View adds a view and segue to another view controller.

I removed the default view controller and added a `UICollectionViewController` instead, then I created a Segue by control-drag from Container View to the newly created `UICollectionViewController` and selected embed. See image in the link (Not enough privileges to add images to post yet)

[image: Image Shows Storyboard with Container View and UICollectionViewController]

When running the application the cells aren't showing. In case you wonder, I have set the number of sections, the data source and `cellForItemAt` with its `dequeueReusableCell`.

Why aren't the cells showing?

As you can see in the image below, in the simulator the black cell is not showing.

[image: Image shows Simulator and XCode storyboard]

I want to thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: You are telling "I did this, I did that" without showing a single line of code.  Nobody can tell what you have not done without seeing some.

Comment: Is all storyboard, the only code is in the container view controller has the UICollectionView data source, delegate, and flow layout

Comment: Yeah @JamesRichard you need to show us the code where you deque the cells. I suspect that the collection view's delegate and datasource is not correctly handled.

Comment: But do get in touch with me if you couldn't find a solution, I'm offering anyone 15-20 minutes free debugging :)

Comment: @Chan Jing Hong - How do I get in touch? I'm interested in the consultation

Comment: You can get in touch with me on twitter @cjinghong

Comment: @cjinghong done!

Comment: @Chan Jing Hong. Sent you a msg to tw ter account, no response yet.